# ASP.NET MVC 4 ModelState.IsValid is always false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I realize that this question has been asked before, but I do not see a solution to my issue anywhere. So, I am trying to familiarize myself with MVC. I am using MVC 4, with bootstrap. I am trying to create a contact form. I was following a tutorial and got this below.

Here is the viewmodel data:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the cshtml data:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @if (ViewBag.Message == null)
        {
            <div>
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Name">Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name"
                              class="text-muted"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Email">Email</label>
                        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Email"
                              class="text-muted"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Subject">Subject</label>
                        <input asp-for="Subject" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Subject"
                              class="text-muted"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Message">Message</label>
                        <textarea rows="5" cols="15"
                                  asp-for="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Message"
                              class="text-muted"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">
                            Send
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        }

        <div>
            <div>
                @if (ViewBag.Message != null){
                    <div>@ViewBag.Message</div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller data:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = null;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage msz = new MailMessage();
                msz.From = new MailAddress(vm.Email);//Email which you are getting 
                                                     //from contact us page 
                msz.To.Add("email");//Where mail will be sent 
                msz.Subject = vm.Subject;
                msz.Body = vm.Message;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

                smtp.Port = 587;

                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                ("user", "password has been removed");

                smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                smtp.Send(msz);

                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.Message = "Thanks, your message has been sent.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.Message = $"It seems an error has been encountered. Please, try again later. Thank you. If you contact customer support, send them this : {ex.Message}";
            }
        } else
        {
            var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(z => z.Exception));
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The output of the var 'errors' =

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__16<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, System.Web.Mvc.ModelState>, System.Exception>}
```

My issue is that the code always says that ModelState.IsValid is always false. Why is that so? Thank you.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I have my model declared at the top of my cshtml page.
It is declared as `@model [namespacehere].ViewModel.ContactViewModel`

Comment: Are you sure you have submitted all required form fields ? Also do `return View(vm);` if `ModelState.IsValid` is false (in your else condition). Then you can see the validation errors in the form.

Comment: You can add a `.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()` and see what the error messages actually are if @Shyju's suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: Shyju's suggestion didn't return anything, it simply emptied the input fields.... Can you explain how to add your suggestion, Jacob? Sorry, I do not know much about MVC other than the basics.

Comment: `public static List<string> GetModelErrors (ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            var query = from state in modelState.Values
                        from error in state.Errors
                        select error.ErrorMessage;

            return query.ToList();
        }`

Comment: Alright, so I've added this in and I am returning 4 'errors'. There is one error for each field, and it says that the field is required. I.E. ('Name' is required.) I thought this was being handles by the model... Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, I should note that I do have the model declared at the top of my cshtml page. I'll update the post above.

Comment: Since all of declared model properties are required fields, you need to bind them on view using Razor html helpers instead of plain HTML tags. I recommend all input and textarea tag(s) should be changed with `TextBoxFor` and `TextAreaFor` with htmlattributes (i.e. class & asp-for) to ensure user's input passed to model successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think MVC 4 does not support TagHelpers since they were introduced in MVC 6.

Check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/08/06/a-complete-guide-to-the-mvc-6-tag-helpers/) out.

You could use good old

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.{Property})
```

and

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.{Property})
```

Another solution is to set "name" tag of your inputs to the name of the property. Ex.:

```
<input name="Subject" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: So simple, yet so true. I set the name tag for each input as you said and it now works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help)